# What version of CE is Window Mobile 6.5 built on?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

Windows Mobile 5 was based on CE 5.0.

Windows Mobile 6 was based on CE 5.2.

Does anyone know what version of CE is used by Windows Mobile 6.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=3204746) indicate that WM6.5 is also based on CE 5.2 (specifically 5.2.21139).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's still a CE 5.0 base - it's not using the CE 6.0 kernel.